# Holomorphic function with $f\circ f=f$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to solve this problem but i have no idea how to do ...Thanks!

Let be $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a holomorphic function.
Show that if $f\circ f=f$ then f is either constant or $f(z)=z \ \forall\ z\in\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Differentiating helps.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $f(z)-z =0$ for all $z\in f(\mathbb{C})$.  If $f$ is not constant then $f(\mathbb{C})$ is open.  In that case $f(z)-z=0$ on an open set and so $f(z)-z$ is identically $0$. (In fact it suffices that $f(\mathbb{C})$ is either a single point or not discrete.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Differentiate $$f(f(z))=f(z).$$

Comment: Well, i can differentiate and i have $f'(f(z))f'(z)=f'(z)$, and now?

Comment: @Alessandro $(f'(f(z))-1)f'(z)=0$. Since both factors are analytic one of them has to be identically zero (follows from the identity theorem for analytic functions).

Comment: Thanks!I had prove to solve problem in this way, but i had not remember that holomorphic functions have this propriety...Thanks!